# The jade template can't render content that have html tag?

Tags: html, tags, render, pug

My jade template is

```
div.article
 #{content}
```

the content is `<p>Sample Test</p>`

so the render result should be

```
<div class="article">
  <p>Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

but the render result is

```
   <div class="artichle">
    <<p>Sample Text</p>></<p>Sample Text</p>>
   </div>
```

Why this happened? How can I render the content with html tag correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the unescaped variant of tag texts :

```
- var html = "<script></script>"
| !{html}
```

See https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#tag-text for the full explanation

In your example you would write :

```
div.article
  !{content}
```

Notice that you should be careful with injecting html unescaped code. It may contain cross-site hacks depending on your use case (injecting a redirect in a comment)